# Is it required to initiate the chrome driver in the scope of class?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testing

I declared my Chrome driver inside the `invokeBrowser()` method as below in the code for the purpose of launching the Chrome driver only. The second method called `searchItem()`, driver doesn't act as a chrome driver since I haven't declared the chrome driver inside the second method or not in the class cope. But my code is still working fine where the Chrome driver launches successfully then invokes the second method and does the required elements findings.

```
public class Day1 {

    WebDriver driver; 

    public void invokeBrowser()
    {
try {
    
           System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Selenium webdriver jars\\ChromeDriver                      \\chromedriver-win32\\chromedriver-win32\\chromedriver.exe");

           driver=new ChromeDriver();

          

} catch (Exception e) {
    
    e.printStackTrace();
}

    }

        public void searchItem()
    {
        
        try {
            
        
            driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.get("https://www.amazon.com/amazonprime");
                        driver.findElement(By.id("twotabsearchtextbox")).sendKeys("watches");
                        Thread.sleep(3000);
                        driver.findElement(By.id("nav-search-submit-button")).click();
            
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
        

        Day1 myObj = new Day1();
        myObj.invokeBrowser();
        myObj.searchItem();
        
    }

}
```

My question is: since the Chrome driver class has its own methods that are implemented for the Chrome browser, should this driver act as a Chrome driver always and do we need to declare it within the class scope? What is the best practice? Is the way I declare the chrome driver not correct?

Comment: your WebDriver is declared in the scope of Day1 class.   Better to initialize the driver in the constructor, though.  That would avoid being able to use the searchItem() method before the driver is initialized.  (you'd get a null pointer if you used that method before "invokeBrowser()" there...)

Comment: Personally I like using a factory style class that creates a driver and returns it.  That way any class can call it to create a new instance, but it's certainly not needed.  In your case, you'd call that to initialize your driver in the constructor, but you could also use that "factory" for multi-threading drivers/browsers.   A "best practice" might be that initializing properties is generally a good thing to avoid nulls.  You can always change the value later if you like, but null pointers can sometimes be tricky to debug.

Comment: More to your point though...  as I think I misread the question... you are declaring the type as WebDriver.  You're initializing as ChromeDriver.   In Java this means the "driver" property of the Day1 class is now both a WebDriver and a ChromeDriver.  (WebDriver is an interface which ChromeDriver implements)  ALL methods/properties of WebDriver will work... ALL methods/properties of ChromeDriver will work.  You could however, take arguments when initializing that specify that you want to launch another type which also implements WebDriver... i.e. launching Firefox with GeckoDriver)

Comment: If a method uses only WebDriver methods/properties, the code can be the same for all drivers that implement WebDriver.  If a method uses methods/properties that only work for a specific driver you might need some branching.  Selenium has tried to include bools in WebDriver spec that tell you if the driver supports something so that you could branch... (i.e. "HasCDP", "HasDevTools", etc...) but sometimes try/catch might be necessarily.  (Which is why you'll see things like typing to (TakesScreenshot) or (JavascriptExecutor) because not all drivers implement it.)

Comment: hi pcalkins, thanks for your explanation. Actually, I agree with all the points you mentioned here. But my original question addresses the third point you mentioned. Actually, as you can see web driver acts as a Chrome driver only inside my invokeBrowser() method but inside the searchItem() method still acts as a webdriver (not a specific browser type) but the rest of the code (code under searchItem() method )  still working on the Chrome browser. In this case,  how does this code still work on the Chrome browser?

Comment: because your instance is a ChromeDriver.  It's also everything else that ChromeDriver implements (it implements many different interfaces), but more importantly when you initialize it with ...new ChromeDriver(), the chromedriver executable is launched.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of way:

My favorite is by abstractions:

```java
public abstract class DriverManager {
    private WebDriver driver;
    private WebElement currentElement;
    public DriverManager() {
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }

    public DriverManager navigate(String url) {
        driver.navigate().to(url);
        return this;
    }

    public DriverManager click() {
        currentElement.click();
        return this;
    }
}
```

```java
public class HomePage extends DriverManager {
    public void start() {
        this
                .navigate("http://localhost")
                .click();
    }
}
```

Singleton is also a good way to do it